# Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now - error on TYPO3 backend module of EXT:indexed_search

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-indexed-search

In the production environment of my TYPO3 8.7 installation I get this error message when I try to open the TYPO3 backend module "Indexing":

```
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now 

Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException thrown in file
/home/www/html-data/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php in line 280.
```

The problem seems to be in the loop in vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/Domain/Repository/AdministrationRepository.php in function getRecordsNumbers()

After some research it seems that `closeCursor()` is necessary, but I wasn't able to integrate that.

The funny thing is, that the error only occurs in my production environment. On the development machine, everything works fine!

So is this now a TYPO3 bug or a configuration problem of my production machine?

My environment:

- TYPO3 8.7.20
- Production:

  - PHP 7.2.8
  - MySQL 5.6.37
  - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev
- Development:

  - PHP 7.2.7
  - MySQL 5.5.60
  - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev

Only difference is that in the development environment pdo_mysql is not present.

[image]

Comment: As suggested I've posted this problem also to Forge: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the index of the database table `index_rel` was broken.

Deleting the table and rebuilding it solved my problem.